# Why Drop trait is only executed at the end of the scope, instead of after the last use?

Tags: rust, reference, drop

This is a question from [rust onomicon # lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetimes.html#the-area-covered-by-a-lifetime)

The first example can compile, as x is a reference and the compiler can infer its lifetime as minimal as the last use here :`println!()`, so x is dropped after this line.

```rust
let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];
let x = &data[0];
println!("{}", x);
// This is OK, x is no longer needed
data.push(4);
```

But the case is different when x is a struct implemented Drop trait.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X<'a>(&'a i32);

impl Drop for X<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];
let x = X(&data[0]);
println!("{:?}", x);
data.push(4);
// Here, the destructor is run and therefore this'll fail to compile.
```

The onomicon says in this case, `drop()` is only executed at the very end of a scope, so x keeps valid until the last line.

But why the compiler cannot minimize the lifetime of x to the last use? And is applying `drop()` just after the last use has some nontrivial side effects when x is implemented Drop trait?

Comment: It would probably be possible to design a language like you suggest, but Rust isn't that language, and it can't be changed at this point due to the backwards compatibility guarantees that Rust gives. In Rust 1.0, the notion of liveness used by the borrow checker and the scopes used for drop analysis were identical. "Non-lexical lifetimes" or NLL relaxed the borrow checker, which was a backwards-compatible change. As mentioned before, it's not possible to change the point `drop()` is run without breaking bompatibility, but it's also not clear whether it would be desirable to do so.

Comment: The primary reason is that someone at some point defined it to be like that. And changing it now would break stuff.

Many existing Rust libraries rely on this; even the standard library relies on it. For example a [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html) relies on the fact that the lock will only be dropped once the scope is left.

Comment: @Finomnis I agree with your point, but I'm not sure `MutexGuard` is a good example, since it's usually used to protect access to the value it wraps, in which case it would be fine to drop it after the last use.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Although not best practices, but I've seen people use `Mutex<()>` to write multi-threaded code in the old-fashioned C++ style. The primary reason I used it is because I couldn't come up with a better example quickly :D

Comment: Another example is [`tracing::Span::enter`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/span/struct.Span.html#method.enter) which also relies on the fact that the returned `Entered` guard will stay alive until the end of the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary reason is that it was once defined to be like that, and now changing it isn't possible any more because it wouldn't be backwards-compatible and might break stuff.

Your code is easily fixable by introducing a nested scope, though, which is (to my understanding) best practice in those situations:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X<'a>(&'a i32);

impl Drop for X<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];
    {
        let x = X(&data[0]);
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
    data.push(4);
}
```

```
X(1)
```

Alternatively, you could `drop` it manually:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X<'a>(&'a i32);

impl Drop for X<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let x = X(&data[0]);
    println!("{:?}", x);
    drop(x);

    data.push(4);
}
```

```
X(1)
```